# Flutter BorderRadius of Card doesn't apply for child: Container?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have the follwing code and I wonder how to make Container take the Cards BorderRadius? The only way I know is to add BorderRadius to BoxDecoration of Container, but is this the right way? How could I do better?

```
              Align(
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Color(0xff232526),Color(0xff414345) ],
                        begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                       // stops: [0.1,1],
                        end: Alignment.topCenter,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: RadialGauge(
                      counter: snapshot.data['Strom'].toDouble(),
                    ).buildGauge(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine to do so. And don't use clipping, since it's considered as a heavy operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use Clip.hardEdge, will cut out the excess

```
Card(
              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
              elevation: 10,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child:...
```

Answer (score 0):

in your boxDeocration of the  containner add this

```dart
borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(radius),
```